# Hide class if other class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div classes

```
<div class="foo"> </div>
<div class="fooz"> </div>
```

I want "foo" to hide if "fooz" doesn't exists. Actually "foo" is a conditional class and needed when "fooz" exists otherwise hidden.

i found this code browsing stackflow questions

```
if($('.fooz').length)
$('#foo').show();
```

But it not working!

Any help how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo` is a class use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), also I think you can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) here to set the display

```
$('.foo').toggle($('.fooz').length > 0);
```

Demo: [With fooz](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FN53b/), [without](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FN53b/2/)

Answer (score 2):

your mistake was using id instead of class:

```
if($('.fooz').length)
$('.foo').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$('.foo').show();
```

since it's a class not an `ID`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$(".foo").show()`, instead of `$("#foo").show()`, since `foo` is  a class, not an id

Answer (score 0):

In your cass, foo is not an id but it's a class. So you should use:

```
if($('.fooz').length)
    $('.foo').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// if there is at-least 1 element with .fooz class
//   Show .foo
// else
//   hide .foo
var tog = $('.fooz').length ? 'show' : 'hide';

$('.foo')[tog]();
```